# How to check if a template type is one of the types of a variant type?

Tags: c++, boost, type-traits, c++98, boost-variant

Considering a variant type and a template function, **how can I check the template type is one of the types of the variant ?** Is there a more elegant way than the following ?

```
typedef boost::variant<Foo,Bar> Var;

template <typename T>
void f(const T& x)
{
  BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(
       boost::is_same<T,Foo>::value
    || boost::is_same<T,Bar>::value
  );
}
```

**Note :** I use Boost 1.57 and gcc 4.8.3. **I don't use C++11** for compatibility with old gcc versions.

Comment: You may do a traits `contains` (but without variadic from c++11, not sure it is more elegant).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use MPL:

```
#include <boost/variant/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/contains.hpp>

typedef boost::variant<Foo, Bar> Var;

template <typename T>
void f(const T& x)
{
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(boost::mpl::contains<Var::types, T>::value);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/310e43c81d2c5078)

or manually iterate over `boost:::variant` types:

```
#include <boost/variant/variant_fwd.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>

template <typename T, typename V>
struct variant_has_type;

template <typename T, BOOST_VARIANT_ENUM_SHIFTED_PARAMS(typename Ts)>
struct variant_has_type<T, boost::variant<T, BOOST_VARIANT_ENUM_SHIFTED_PARAMS(Ts)> >
    : boost::true_type {};

template <typename T, typename U, BOOST_VARIANT_ENUM_SHIFTED_PARAMS(typename Ts)>
struct variant_has_type<T, boost::variant<U, BOOST_VARIANT_ENUM_SHIFTED_PARAMS(Ts)> >
    : variant_has_type<T, boost::variant<BOOST_VARIANT_ENUM_SHIFTED_PARAMS(Ts), void> > {};

template <typename T, BOOST_VARIANT_ENUM_SHIFTED_PARAMS(typename Ts)>
struct variant_has_type<T, boost::variant<void, BOOST_VARIANT_ENUM_SHIFTED_PARAMS(Ts)> >
    : boost::false_type {};
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/964a3c31c5cafdbc)