# How to make a template function enabled if one of variant's types?

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming, type-traits, variant

I have some variant `using V = std::variant<A, B, C>` and some function `foo` with the prototype `void foo(const T&)`.

And want my function `foo` to be `std::enable_if`ed if one of `V`'s types are passed (without indicating them explicitly).

My `V` will get more and more types in time, because of that, solution like

```
template<class T,
         typename std::enable_if<
            std::is_same_v<T, A> || std::is_same_v<T, B> || std::is_same_v<T, C>,
            int>::type = 0>
void foo(const T&);
```

is not acceptable.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538945/how-to-check-if-a-template-type-is-one-of-the-types-of-a-variant-type) is a boost solution.

Is it possible to implement the logic for `std::variant`?

Ideally, the type trait should look like `is_one_of_variants_types<V, T>`.

Comment: A variant can be any of the types; what does foo do if the variant isn't actually a valid alternative?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont, `foo` takes some of variant's types, not the variant itself. (Those types of the variant may be variants themselves, yet that shouldn't affect the solution.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
template <typename, typename>
constexpr bool is_one_of_variants_types = false;

template <typename... Ts, typename T>
constexpr bool is_one_of_variants_types<std::variant<Ts...>, T>
    = (std::is_same_v<T, Ts> || ...);

template <typename T>
auto foo(const T&)
    -> std::enable_if_t<is_one_of_variants_types<V, T>>;
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cccd46d73e942780)

Answer (score 2):

> And want my function foo to be `std::enable_if` ed if one of `V`'s types are passed (without indicating them explicitly).

I suppose you can simply try, inside a `decltype()`, to `emplace()` a `T` value inside a `V` value.

I mean... something as follows

```
#include <variant>
#include <type_traits>

struct A {};
struct B {};
struct C {};

using V = std::variant<A, B, C>;

template <typename T>
auto foo (T const & t)
   -> std::void_t<decltype( std::declval<V>().emplace<T>(t) )>
 { }

int main ()
 {
   foo(A{});  // compile
   // foo(0); // compilation error
 }
```

Obviously this works only if all variant types are different and with a copy constructor (implicit or explicit).

Comment: thank you for the smart solution! May you please explain why `Obviously this works only if all variant types are different.`?

Comment: Because the `emplace<T, Args...>()` method is available only if `T` occurs exactly one times in `Tipes...` (given a `std::variant<Tipes...>`). Not the only problem: `T` must be constructible from a `T` value, so you needs a copy constructor (implicit, as in my example, or explicit) for every type in `Tipes...`. So, yes: it's a smart solution; but with a couple of great limits.

Comment: Thank you! Didn’t know that. I’ve tested your solution. Some more limitations: the types cannot be incomplete (i.e. forward declared types won’t compile if foo is used before their definitions) and, of course, limitations on constructors are painful.

Comment: @Nestor - yes... the incompleteness is another problem.